# how to add NonCPS annotation to test a groovy class used in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm new to groovy. Been using it for a few weeks. I wrote a class that is used in Jenkins as a shared library. The simple methods and structure works fine.

But I'm planning to make it bigger, so I want to add unit tests to it. Right now I just want to import the class in a script, and run some asserts. But I get the following error:

```
unable to resolve class NonCPS ,  unable to find class for annotation
@ line 51, column 2.
    @NonCPS
```

The annotation is required by Jenkins.

The library (which again works) something like:

```
class MyTestClass implements Serializable {
  MyTestClass() { }
  @NonCPS
  def testMethod() { }
```

in the script I call

```
import com.blabla.MyTestClass
...
test = new MyTestClass()
```

if I just comment the annotation for testing it works.
I've been searching around and have seem some pretty cool projects to test Jenkins pipelines including their shared libraries, but I'm a little confused right now I would like to just get this tests before using more sophisticated things.

From the groovy documentation, I understand that the annotation should go in a class definition and not a method (is this correct?) but then how is it that this works when being run on Jenkins?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you want to compile your shared library outside Jenkins runtime environment then you have to add [groovy-cps](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.cloudbees/groovy-cps/1.24) dependency to your classpath and add an import:

```
import com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.NonCPS
```

to the class that uses `@NonCPS` annotation. It does not break anything - Jenkins when prepares runtime environment for Jenkinsfile execution it adds the same import and when this import is present it does not make any collision.

I would also recommend using Gradle to define dependencies and build your shared library on CI server. The minimum `build.gradle` file may look like this:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'idea'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets {
  main {
    groovy {
      srcDirs = ['src', 'vars']
    }
  }
  test {
    groovy {
      srcDirs = ['test']
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.cloudbees:groovy-cps:1.22'
  compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.12'

  testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4'
}
```

It uses `src` and `vars` as a source files directories and `test` as a unit test directory. My shared library directory structure usually looks like this:

```
├── build.gradle
├── Jenkinsfile
├── src
│   └── com
│       └── foo
├── test
│   ├── com
│   │   └── foo
│   └── vars
│       └── myVarSpec.groovy
└── vars
    └── myVar.groovy
```

In this example we use 2 compile time dependencies - `groovy-cps` and `groovy-all`, and Spock Framework for unit tests. Thanks to this you can run unit tests inside your IDE as well as on CI server with `gradle test` command.

#### Jenkins pipeline unit test library

When running a simple unit tests is not enough, consider using [JenkinsPipelineUnit](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit) library that allows you test your Jenkinsfiles including shared libraries. This is a great library that speeds up development and you can test your pipeline behavior in just a couple of milliseconds. This library works with JUnit, however there is some 3rd party wrapper that brings this library to Spock (I haven't test it though).

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you! I didn't think adding the `import` to a file in `vars/` would work, but it did.